# how to predict the name of zip folder generated by windows?

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, zip

I am going to prepare a (windows) server side service which allows users to download their requested files as a Zipped folder. In Microsoft windows(7) If you select all files and folders and send them to a zip folder, a random name will be assigned to the generated zip file which is the name of one files or folders in that collection.

Is there any reason that windows doesn't set a new name say new-zip-file? and how can I predict what the name would be?

Comment: What method are you using to zip the files?  Is there some reason you can't just specify a file name for the resulting .zip file?

Comment: I am searching if there a way to use windows capabilities rather than writing script or using winrar as third-party handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the zip is in fact not random,
it relies in the file you choose to click at last.

you can select multiple files but you make right click on one only file in order to zip the group of files, and thats the file name windows chooose.